What is it called when a weed has an intentionally weak connection to the roots?
I feel like I have seen this mostly with weeds, but it might be a common trait in other non weedy plants. Basically, it's that the main above-ground body of the plant has a weak connection to the roots. This seems like an adaptation to prevent casual pulling(maybe also grazing?) from completely removing the plant from the ground and allowing it regrow from the still intact and underground root. I've experienced it with most recently when hand pulling dandelions and common mallow plants. I have to grab the plant a little below the soil line to actually get the whole thing and prevent it from immediately regrowing.
Is there a name for that trait?

I haven't been able to find a definitive answer, but it seems like it's only a feature of plants with taproots. Other root systems don't store enough nutrients to regenerate readily when the top is removed

ask at https://biology.stackexchange.com/

@jsotola I would say the question is on topic here(and a pretty good one) instead on Biology.SE. We're weed pullers and they are professors of reading.

@Vorac we may be weed pullers,  but they are the namers of plant features
